# How to get the following integral: $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-r)}(t-r)^{-3/2}dr.$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I try to get the following integral:

$$
\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-r)}(t-r)^{-3/2}dr
$$
where $\alpha>0$. If not, the upper bound for this integral is fine.

Actually, I want to get $$\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-r)}(t-r)^{-3/2}dr.$$

---

First, I take $x=t-r$, then the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^t e^{-\alpha x}x^{-3/2}dx.
$$

So by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}x^{-3/2}dx=\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{\alpha^{-1/2}}
$$

Am I right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the gamma function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral does not converge for any $t > 0$. This is because there exists such $a > 0$ that $e^{-\alpha x} > a$ for all $x \in [0, t]$. It follows that
$$
\int_0^t e^{-\alpha x} x^{-3/2} dx > \int_0^t ax^{-3/2} dx = \frac{-2a}{\sqrt{x}} \Big|_0^t = \frac{-2a}{t} + \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2a}{x} = \infty.
$$

You might be interested in the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), specifically $\Gamma(-1/2)$, which gives a value to this integral by analytic continuation. Knowing that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ (proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)) and $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$ we conclude that $\Gamma(1/2)=-\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(-1/2)$, which implies $\Gamma(-1/2) = -2\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: But I think that is Gamma function $
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}x^{-3/2}dx=\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{\alpha^{-1/2}}
$? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Am I right? But I do not know why for fix $t$, this integral does not converge. But when integrate from 0 to $\infty$, it will be a gamma function?

Comment: @Hermi, for $t > 0$ the singularity is too strong at the upper endpoint of the integral, $r = t$. Things are quite different if, for some reason, you were to consider $e^{-\alpha(t-r)} - 1$.

Comment: @Aruralreader So if the upper point is $\infty$ of this integral, this integral is just finite and this is a Gamma function?

Comment: @Hermi, no, the upper endpoint $t$ also appears in the integrand. You want to rethink the derivation that led to this.

Comment: @Aruralreader I am confused. Does this one correct? $
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}x^{-3/2}dx=\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{\alpha^{-1/2}}
$?

Comment: The gamma function has **that** definition $\;\Gamma(t):=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx\;$ *only* for $\;t\in\Bbb C\,,\;\;\text{Re}(t)>0\;$ .We can certainly extend analytically the gamma function to all the complex real numbers which aren't zero or negative integers...but then it is *not* that definition above, and in your case you $\;\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}x^{-1-1/2}dx...t=-1\;$ !